# How can I do mathematical operations of a subset of data in data table?

Tags: r, data.table

As the question says, I want to modify a subset of data.

Example:

```
library(data.table)
v1 <- rep(c(4.5, 3.5, 4.0, 1.0, 4.0, 3.5, 4.5, 4.0, 1.0, 4.0, 
             3.0, 4.5, 4.0, 3.0, 1.5, 1.5, 2.0, 2.0,
             3.5, 4.5, 3.5, 3.5, 4.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 2.5, 4.5),100)
v2 <- rep(c(4.5, 3.5, 1.5, 1.0, 4.0, 1.5, 4.5, 1.5, 1.0, 4.0, 
            3.0, 1.5, 1.5, 3.0, 1.5, 1.5, 2.0, 2.0,
            3.5, 1.5, 3.5, 3.5, 1.5, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 2.5, 4.5),100)

dt <- data.table(v1, v2)
```

Then I want to slice out a subset and do mathematical operations on it, but dont want to change the rest of the data.

I am looking for something like followed:

```
dT <- dT[v1 <= 5.0 & v1 > 4.4] * 100
```

Comment: You just apply it to the subset with `dT[v1 <= 5.0 & v1 > 4.4] <- dT[v1 <= 5.0 & v1 > 4.4] * 100`

Comment: It throws an error. ``error in `[.data.table`(dT, v1 <= 5 & v1 > 4.4) : 
  i evaluates to a logical vector length 2800 but there are 2554 rows.``

Comment: I just tested it and it was simply to reference the table. This works: `dt[dt$v1 <= 5.0 & dt$v1 > 4.4] <- dt[dt$v1 <= 5.0 & dt$v1 > 4.4] * 100`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find below one possible solution.

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(data.table)

dt[v1 <= 5.0 & v1 > 4.4] <- dt[, .SD[v1 <= 5.0 & v1 > 4.4] * 100]
```

- Output

```r
dt
#>          v1    v2
#>    1: 450.0 450.0
#>    2:   3.5   3.5
#>    3:   4.0   1.5
#>    4:   1.0   1.0
#>    5:   4.0   4.0
#>   ---            
#> 2796:   3.0   3.0
#> 2797:   4.0   4.0
#> 2798:   4.0   4.0
#> 2799:   2.5   2.5
#> 2800: 450.0 450.0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

One alternative (and more efficient) solution which update columns by reference.

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(data.table)

ColsToBeModified <- c("v1", "v2")
dt[v1 <= 5.0 & v1 > 4.4, (ColsToBeModified) := lapply(.SD, \(x) x * 100), .SDcols = ColsToBeModified][]
```

- Output

```r
#>          v1    v2
#>    1: 450.0 450.0
#>    2:   3.5   3.5
#>    3:   4.0   1.5
#>    4:   1.0   1.0
#>    5:   4.0   4.0
#>   ---            
#> 2796:   3.0   3.0
#> 2797:   4.0   4.0
#> 2798:   4.0   4.0
#> 2799:   2.5   2.5
#> 2800: 450.0 450.0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Subset the rows and multiply all columns by a constant and save the result:

```
dt <- dt[v1 <= 5.0 & v1 > 4.4, lapply(.SD, \(x) x * 100)]
```

If you want to modify in-place just the selected rows you could:

```
dt[v1 <= 5.0 & v1 > 4.4, (names(dt)) := lapply(.SD, \(x) x * 100)]
```